# What parameters should be modified after upgrading RAM memory in Oracle server

Tags: oracle, linux, memory, parameter

I have a linux server (rhel4) with oracle 9i (9.2.0.8) to which we have recently upgraded the RAM memory from 4G to 16G. I would like to know what server parameters I should modify and even more what Oracle parameters should I modify to make use of this new configuration from memory, thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

In 9i, multiple parameters are used for sizing components of the SGA. Below is a typical (but not complete) list:

[DB_CACHE_SIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96536/ch139.htm#1016009)

[JAVA_POOL_SIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96536/ch181.htm#1017936)

[LARGE_POOL_SIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96536/ch184.htm#1018084)

[SHARED_POOL_SIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96536/ch1194.htm#1024090)

And [SGA_MAX_SIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96536/ch1190.htm#1023915), if set.

Also I assume for simplicity that you use automatic PGA management, so for PGA:

[PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96536/ch1158.htm#1022446)